# How should I declare a long in Objective-C? Is NSInteger appropriate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I see `NSInteger` is used quite often and the `typedef` for it on the iPhone is a long, so technically I could use it when I am expect int(64) values. But should I be more explicit and use something like `int64_t` or long directly? What would be the downside of just using long?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IIRC, `long` on the iPhone/ARM is 32 bits. If you want a guaranteed 64-bit integer, you should (indeed) use `int64_t`.

Comment: Yeah, NSInteger will be the native word type.

Comment: On x86 `long` is also 32-bit.

Comment: @KennyTM: that depends on the OS and compilers, not just the hardware.

Comment: @Stephan: True. But in this context, the compiler must be gcc or clang, and the OS must be Mac OS X.

Comment: @KennyTM: and if the executable is built 64-bit on OS X / x86, `long` is 64 bits wide.

Comment: But it's not, since the OP is asking about the iPhone. /shrug

Comment: (NB: 4 years later, we now have 64-bit iOS devices.)

Answer (score 2):

## Integer Data Types Sizes

- `short` - *ILP32*: 2 bytes; *LP64*: 2 bytes
- `int` - *ILP32*: 4 bytes; *LP64*: 4 bytes
- `long` - *ILP32*: 4 bytes; *LP64*: 8 bytes
- `long long` - *ILP32*: 8 bytes; *LP64*: 8 bytes

It may be useful to know that:

> The compiler defines the `__LP64__` macro when compiling for the 64-bit runtime.

`NSInteger` is a `typedef` of `long` so it will be 32-bits in a 32-bit environment and 64-bits in a 64-bit environment.

When converting to 64-bit you can simply replace all your `int`s and `long`s to `NSInteger` and you *should* be good to go.

**Important:** pay attention to the alignment of data, *LP64* uses natural alignment for all Integer data types but *ILP32* uses 4 bytes for all Integer data types with size equal to or greater than 4 bytes.

You can read more about 32 to 64 bit conversion in the Official [**64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html).

Answering you questions:

> How should I declare a long in Objective-C? Is NSInteger appropriate?

You can use either `long` or `NSInteger` but `NSInteger` is more idiomatic IMHO.

> But should I be more explicit and use something like int64_t or long directly?

If you expect consistent 64-bit sizes neither `long` nor `NSInteger` will do, you'll have to use `int64_t` (as [Wevah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14256/wevah) said).

> What would be the downside of just using long?

It's not idiomatic and you may have problems if Apple rolls out a new architecture again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a type of known specific size, use the type that has that known specific size: `int64_t`.

If you need a generic integer type and the size is not important, go ahead and use `int` or `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

[NSInteger's](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16) length depends on whether you are compiling for 32 bit or 64 bit.  It's defined as long for 64 bit and iPhone and int for 32 bit.

So on iPhone the length of NSInteger is the same as the length of a long, which is compiler dependent.  Most compilers make long the same length as the native word. i.e. 32 bit for 32 bit architectures and 64 bit for 64 bit architectures.

Given the uncertainty over the width of NSInteger, I use it only for types of variables to be used in the Cocoa API when NSInteger is specified.  If I need a fixed width type, I go for the ones defined in `stdint.h`.  If I don't care about the width I use the C built in types

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare something as long, declare it as long. Be aware that long can be 32 or 64 bit, depending on the compiler.

If you want to declare something to be as efficient as possible, and big enough to count items, use NSInteger or NSUInteger. Note that both can be 32 or 64 bits, and can be actually different types (int or long), depending on the compiler. Which protects you from mixing up types in some cases.

If you want 32 or 64 bit, and nothing else, use int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t. Be aware that either type can be unnecessarily inefficient on some compiler.