# What is the int64_t format specifier for NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cannot find the right format specifier for `int64_t`

```
int64_t var;

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value is: %?? ",var];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604137/definition-of-int64-t and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985008/how-should-i-declare-a-long-in-objective-c-is-nsinteger-appropriate

Comment: I looked at this answer but I didn't find a solution especially when it comes to 32bits 64 bits platform compatibility.

Comment: @NicolasManzini: You can directly use the first answer to that question: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value is: %" PRId64 "", var]` works on all platforms.

Comment: should I close or delete this post?

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
int64_t var;    
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value is: %lld",var];
```

Comment: Alternatively boxing the number as an object is quite nice i.e. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value is: %@",@(var)]`